# What are these matrix identities called?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

The first one seems to be a slightly modified Woodbury inversion formula, but I can't find the second one.

$(P^{-1} + B^\top R^{-1} B)^{-1} = P-P B^\top (BPB^\top + R)^{-1} BP$
$(P^{-1} + B^\top R^{-1} B)^{-1} B^\top R^{-1} = P B^\top (BPB^\top + R)^{-1}$

I found it in [this](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/teaching/ICS274Bspring06/PCA.ps) explanation of PCA.

I'd like to use it in my thesis but I don't know how to refer to it.

Comment: I used both of these in working on Lattice QCD way back in the early 80's. But I never new any name to call them; I just used the euqations, which were common lore in the LQCD community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second is the variation of the first one. Multiply the both sides by $B^TR^{-1}$
$$
(P^{−1}+B^⊤R^{−1}B)^{−1}B^⊤R^{−1}=PB^TR^{-1}−PB^T(BPB^⊤+R)^{−1}BPB^TR^{-1}=PB^T(BPB^⊤+R)^{−1}((BPB^⊤+R)R^{-1}-BPB^TR^{-1})=PB^T(BPB^⊤+R)^{−1}
$$